# получение памяти процесса

Tags: winapi

Как получить память процесса[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с помощью winapi? Да, значения регистров уже известны. Отсюда вопрос, можно ли получить ее разыменовывая указатель со значением EIP?

Comment: подключитесь как отладчик к процессу и, если он не будет сопротивлятся, читайте все что хотите.

Comment: уже подключился

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244912/open-process-with-debug-privileges-and-read-write-memory